# How to get the value for an option using ArgResults in dart

Tags: dart

I'm creating a cli dart program and am using the ArgParser and ArgResults to interpret the arguments. I have the following parser definition:

```
var parser = ArgParser()
    ..addOption("dir",
        abbr: "d",
        help: "Enter the root directory from where file purging will start.",
        valueHelp: "/myFiles",
        defaultsTo: "/")
    ..addOption("year",
        abbr: "y",
        help: "Enter the minimum year in file name to purge.",
        valueHelp: "2007",
        defaultsTo: "2005")
    ..addFlag("purge", abbr: "p", defaultsTo: false)
    ..addFlag("verbose", abbr: "v", defaultsTo: false);
  ArgResults argResults;
  try {
    argResults = parser.parse(arguments);
  } catch (e) {
    print("Invalid command line arguments! $e");
    return false;
  }
  print("dir = '${argResults["dir"]}'");
  print("year = '${argResults["year"]}'");
  print("purge = '${argResults["purge"]}'");
  print("verbose = '${argResults["verbose"]}'");
```

When I run the program with arguments (in VS code):

```
"args": ["-d /Volumes/Media/resources/dataFiles", "-year2000", "-v"]
```

I get strange results:

```
dir = ' /Volumes/Media/resources/dataFiles'
year = 'ear2000'
purge = 'false'
verbose = 'true'
```

The options and flags have been parsed, but getting the values for the directory and year seems to have left the blank and the optional part of the year.

What am I doing wrong? Or am I expecting too much from the parser and need to further remove the blank and "ear" from the options myself?

Comment: The full arguments must be used with a double `-` so your command line should be: `..., "--year 2000", ...` https://github.com/dart-lang/args#specifying-options

Comment: Thanks @Mattia, that is exactly right. I made incorrect assumptions as to how the syntax works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, normal Options and Flags require two dash,
like `--mode`:

https://github.com/dart-lang/args#parsing-arguments

but you can define `abbr`, to use a single dash:

https://github.com/dart-lang/args#defining-commands